# get data from table and fill combo box depending on select value Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Suppose there is a table FRUITS:

```
mysql> select * from FRUITS;
+---------+-----------+
| fruitid | fruitname |
+---------+-----------+
|       1 | Orange    |
|       2 | Apple     |
|       3 | Pear      |
|       4 | Banana    |
+---------+-----------+
4 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

I have a view file that contains a form.

Here i have a list where user selects which food he wants, so in the case user selects "fruits" I get data from table FRUITS and fill a combo box....

After the user fills the form, some tables will be updated. During the process I need to consult data from FRUITS table and fill a combo box when user selects fruits in the list of food....

If I were not using Codeigniter I could use

```
<?php
 $conn = mysql_connect('localhost','yourUsernameHere','yourPasswordHere');
 mysql_select_db('testdb',$conn);
 $query = "select fruitid,fruitname from FRUITS order by fruitname";
 $result = mysql_query($query,$conn);
 $selectbox='<select name=\'fruit\'>';
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
     $selectbox.='<option value=\"' . $row['fruitid'] . '\">' . $row['fruitname'] . '</option>';
 }

 $selectbox.='</select>';
 mysql_free_result($result);
 echo $selectbox;
?>
```

to fill a combo box inside the form and then capture that value and send it to insert data to other tables...

How could I do this on Codeigniter, as the queries must be done in controller file...?

## update

let us say I have

## model

```
class Fruits extends CI_Model {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function what_fruits()
    {
        $this->db->select('fruitname');
        $this->db->from('FRUITS');
        $q = $this->db->get('');
        if($q->num_rows() > 0) 
        {
            $data = array();
            foreach($q->result() as $row) 
            {
                $data=$row;
            }
            return $data;
        }
    }
}
```

## Controller

```
class main_form_view extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('main_form_view');
    }

    public function result()
    {
        $this->load->model('Fruits');
        $data['fruitname'] = $this->Fruits->what_fruits(); 

    }
}
```

## views main_form_view

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
    <form method="post">
        <select name="food" id="food" onchange="fill_cb_food(this.value);" >
          <option value="0">fruits</option>
          <option value="1">other1</option>
          <option value="2">other2</option>
        </select>

        //response of ajax call display here.???
       <div class="selectbox" id="id_fruits">
          <select name="fruits" id="fruits">
             <option value="">--Choose fruit--</option>
          </select>
       </div>



    </form>
    </body>
</html>



    function fill_cb_food(id)
    {
       $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "main_form_view/result.php,
                data: "fruit=" + fruitname,
                success: function(html){
                    $("#id_fruits").html(html);
                }
            });
    }
```

So I want to get a combo box with

```
 Orange    
  Apple    
  Pear     
  Banana
```

when user selects Fruits option in the form...

Comment: you can use ajax for this purpose which will hit the controller method pointing to model method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ajax post to fetch data runtime and fill into your combo box..
like:

```
         $.ajax({
                url: 'http://url_to_fetch_fruit_table_data/',
                type: "POST",
                data:data,
                success: function(response) {
                   $("select").html(response);
                }
            });
```

or 
you can also loop and fill using **foraeach**.

Comment: and how to populate the combo box in view file?  `while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
     $selectbox.='<option value=\"' . $row['fruitid'] . '\">' . $row['fruitname'] . '</option>';
 }` what is the analog?

Answer (score 1):

In the model you select any column using '*'.

You have to pass the data to the view-file:

```
class main_form_view extends CI_Controller
{    
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->model('Fruits');
        $data['fruits'] = $this->Fruits->what_fruits(); 
        $this->load->view('main_form_view', $data);
    }
}
```

then you can do in the view-file:

```
<?php foreach($fruits as $fruit): ?>
    <option value="<?php print  $fruit['fruitid'] ?>"><?php print $fruit['fruitname']</option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```